# How to handle slightly changing a method from an installed module?

Tags: python

I have a script that imports a module which has a function that I want to change slightly. Lets say the module has the functions divide and run_program:

```
def _divide(var):
    return 1/var

run_program(x):
    do some stuff
    _divide(x)
    do more stuff
```

Instead, I want it to do

```
def divide(var):
    if var == 0:
        var = 1e-131
    return 1/var

    run_program(x):
        do some stuff
        _divide(x)
        do more stuff
```

I've now changed the function in the module. However, if I want to run the program somewhere else, I need to change the module there as well. 
Because the function I want to change is called from within the module I can't overwrite it (as far as I know). Can I change the function from my script so that I don't have to change the installed module?

---

Edit: The module is https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dirichlet/0.7 the function is:

```
def _init_a(D):
'''Initial guess for Dirichlet alpha parameters given data D'''
    E = D.mean(axis=0)
    E2 = (D**2).mean(axis=0)
    return ((E[0] - E2[0])/(E2[0]-E[0]**2)) * E
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace functions dynamically in Python:

```
import module

old_divide = module._divide

def new_divide(var):
    if var == 0:
        var = 1e-131
    return old_divide(var)

module._divide = new_divide
```

When `run_program` is then called it will use the replacement function; the lookup for `_divide` is done when `run_program` is called, not when the module is loaded.

Comment: Can you please elaborate this?

Comment: @Vivek: Elaborate what exactly?

Comment: I mean, its practical usage and how is this handled internally by python.

Comment: @Vivek: Modules are just objects with attributes; all names in it are just references to objects. You can replace those references at will.

Comment: @Vivek: In that respect modules are no different from instances.

Comment: Aha that's clever. Thanks for that. So how do we call it from run_program. Something like: module._divide(), and how is the arg passed?

Comment: The module I'm importing uses `__all__`, in which `_divide` is not included. I can't reach `_divide` (I tried `module._divide` and `from module import _divide`). Some other way to do this?

Comment: @NiekdeKlein: `__all__` does not *limit* what can be imported, it only limits what `from module import *` will import automatically. Without seeing the module source code, I cannot tell how `_divide` is defined or imported nor propose a better solution.

Comment: @NiekdeKlein: Any chance to see the module you are trying to patch here?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I added the module in my question

Comment: @NiekdeKlein: You need to import `dirichlet.dirichlet` and patch `dirichlet.dirichlet. _init_a` then.

Comment: @NiekdeKlein: That way `_fixedpoint` and `_meanprecision` will find your new version.